# How to robocopy *.doc but not *.docx

Tags: robocopy

With `robocopy D:\OLI1 E:\t95\oli1 /s "*.doc"` I want to mirror all Word 95/2000 documents into a folder tree. Unfortunately this copies all docx-Files, too, as robocopy handles this like the file templates `*.doc?`  or `*.doc*`.

I can copy `*.docx` and then delete `*.docx`. Nonetheless this is far from efficient. Instead of copy robocopy could move the files, too. But then it is arbitary that only DOC but not DOCX would be moved.

edit: Work-PC Windows 10 professional

Are there any solutions with robocopy?

Comment: Robocopy also supports exclude patterns, tried that yet?

Comment: As @DanielB says adding `/xf *.docx` works.  Note this wildcard behaviour it isn't just robocopy - `dir *.doc` or will show .docx too, `del *.doc` will also delete .docx etc.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using on my Windows 8.1 when I use robocopy folder01 folder02 /s "*.doc" it only copies *.doc documents and when I use *.docx it only copies *.docx documents.

Comment: Pitiful robocopy breaking it's own syntax/protocols so it plays nice/easily with other products by the same company

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Daniel B

```
robocopy *.doc  D:\OLI1\ E:\T95\oli1  /s  /xf *.docx  *.docm
```

This works like a charm.